# Cron job in Spring Boot which will run at 1:00 AM UTC every second last saturday of every month

Tags: spring-boot, cron

I am trying to make a cron job in Spring Boot which will run at 1:00 AM UTC every second last saturday of every month. I have done below

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1 * * 6L",zone = "UTC")
```

which I think would run every last saturday of every month at 1:00 AM UTC , but not sure how to make it second last as there maybe 4/5 saturdays in a month so making the cron as

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1 * * 6#3",zone = "UTC")

or

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1 * * 6#4",zone = "UTC")
```

may be erroneous. Kindly suggest.